# Difference between Enable category and include in menu

Tags: category-view

What is the exact difference between Enable Category and Include in Menu. As both do the same thing hiding the category/sub category from front end menu.

Only difference When I make "Enable category" off?

Comment: yes you are right.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge.

Yes, you are right both options are same but only one difference.

So I can explain here.

If you have one category like Test.  so and if you SEO rewrite URL is like test.html

Now if both options are enabled then that URL is accessible. but if you choose a category to disable then that URL not accessible.
but if you choose a category to enable but display in Menu disable but then that URL accessible.

So Plese try that case so you can understand it.
please check https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/category-hidden.html for more information and use.
Thanks